# Using DDHotKey to create user-definable Hot-Key in my Cocoa Application

Tags: cocoa, ddhotkey

Having successfully implemented Dave DeLong's DDHotKey I'm now wondering if it's possible to make the hot-key user definable?

The only code in the app that deals specifically with the HotKey is:

```
- (IBAction)registerHotKey:(id)sender {
DDHotKeyCenter * c = [[DDHotKeyCenter alloc] init];
[c registerHotKeyWithKeyCode:1 modifierFlags:NSControlKeyMask target:self action:@selector(activateMain:) object:window];
[c release];
```

and

```
- (IBAction) unregisterHotKey:(id)sender {
DDHotKeyCenter * c = [[DDHotKeyCenter alloc] init];
[c unregisterHotKeyWithKeyCode:1 modifierFlags:NSControlKeyMask];
[c release];
}
```

I'm thinking that it would be necessary to re-write those sections but I'm not sure if that's true, and if it is true I'm not sure where to begin looking.

It seems to me that it would be necessary to capture keyboard input and perhaps save it as a string...but beyond that I'm really unsure as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, you can make them user-configurable.  You'll need some sort of UI for the user to type a keyboard shortcut themselves (I've used [Shortcut Recorder](http://wafflesoftware.net/shortcut/) in the past).  The info you get from that control should be sufficient to pass to the `DDHotKey` registration functions.

Comment: Alright, I've got Shortcut Recorder added to my project and am now stuck. I'm guessing that I need to somehow create an instance of SRRecorderCell but I can't figure out how to go about doing that. Shortcut Recorder is a sub-project of my main project and my assumption is that I need to somehow tell the main project to look into the subproject to find the SRRecorderCell...but as to how to do that I'm at a loss.